# How do you get the desired dataframe from this JSON file with json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have this JSON file:

```
print(resp2)

{
  "entityId": "process_id_1234",
  "displayName": "splunkd - splunkd",
  "firstSeenTms": 1612578480000,
  "lastSeenTms": 1650316020000,
  "properties": {
    "detectedName": "splunkd",
    "bitness": "64",
    "metadata": [
      {
        "key": "EXE_NAME",
        "value": "splunkd"
      },
      {
        "key": "EXE_PATH",
        "value": "/opt/bin/splunkd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2nd json example: In some cases, there are multiple key and value entries. I need the first occurence of key:EXE_Name, value: and key:EXE_PATH, value pairs. Is this possible?

```
{
  "entityId": "proc_1234",
  "displayName": "oracle12",
  "firstSeenTms": 1639034760000,
  "lastSeenTms": 1650386100000,
  "properties": {
    "detectedName": "oracle.sysman.gcagent.tmmain.TMMain",
    "bitness": "64",
    "jvmVendor": "IBM",
    "metadata": [
      {
        "key": "COMMAND_LINE_ARGS",
        "value": "/usr/local/oracle/oem/agent12c/agent_13.3.0.0.0"
      },
      {
        "key": "EXE_NAME",
        "value": "java"
      },
      {
        "key": "EXE_PATH",
        "value": "/usr/local/oracle/oem/agent*c/agent_*/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java"
      },
      {
        "key": "JAVA_MAIN_CLASS",
        "value": "oracle.sysman.gcagent.tmmain.TMMain"
      },
      {
        "key": "EXE_PATH",
        "value": "/usr/local/oracle/oem/agent12c/agent_13.3.0.0.0/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java"
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

I need to get `entityId` and under `metadata` section, I need to pull `EXE_NAME` and `EXE_PATH` and form a data frame that needs to look like this:

```
entityId          EXE_NAME    EXE_PATH
process_id_1234   splunkd     /opt/bin/splunkd
```

I have tried this:

```
procList = []
pd.json_normalize(resp2)
```

I also tried this:

```
pd.json_normalize(resp2, record_path='properties.metadata', meta=['key', 'value'])
```

But it gave a different result than I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you want to build a pandas DataFrame, you can use `json_normalize` to build a DataFrame and `pivot` it:

```py
df = (pd.json_normalize(resp2, record_path=['properties', 'metadata'],
                        meta=['entityId'])
     .pivot('entityId', 'key', 'value').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
key         entityId  EXE_NAME         EXE_PATH
0    process_id_1234  splunkd  /opt/bin/splunkd
```

**Edit:**

In the case of multiple "EXE_NAME"s or "EXE_PATH"s, you could use `drop_duplicates` before `pivot`:

```py
out = (pd.json_normalize(resp2, record_path=['properties', 'metadata'],
                         meta=['entityId'])
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['key'])
       .query("key in ['EXE_NAME','EXE_PATH']")    # you could remove this line if you want the non-EXE columns as well.
       .pivot('entityId', 'key', 'value').reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
key   entityId EXE_NAME                                           EXE_PATH
0    proc_1234     java  /usr/local/oracle/oem/agent*c/agent_*/oracle_c...
```

Comment: is it possible to pick another record_path with json_normalize.

Comment: @user1471980 In the same call? No. But you can set a different record path and call json_normalize again in a separate call. Then perhaps concatenate the two results. json_normalize is a convenience tool that works for specific kind of json data. It doesn't work for all in the same way

Comment: @user7864386, I need to pick detectedName from this json file. How do I do that

Comment: @user7864386, this is good. I am doing multiple rest request and sometimes, metadata section of the json file is empty. This is normal. However, when metada empty, I need to grap the entityid and detectedName from this json. Any ideas?